# Execution error on Mozilla (activexobject is not defined)

Tags: javascript, activex, mozilla

My source is working in IE but not in Mozilla. Please help me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var adOpenDynamic = 2;
var adLockOptimistic = 3;

/* Path of database.
*/
var strDbPath = "..\\SRVGdb.mdb";

/*
Here is the ConnectionString for Microsoft Access.
If you want to use SQL or other databases, you hav to change the connection string..
eg: SQL => var conn_str = "Provider=sqloledb; Data Source=itdev; Initial Catalog=pubs; User ID=sa;Password=yourpassword";
*/
var conn_str = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + strDbPath;

function getAdoDb(strAdoType) {
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        return new ActiveXObject(strAdoType);
    }
    else {
        return ActiveXObject(strAdoType);
    }
}

function showReports() {
    try {
        var tablevar="<table width=\"100%\" border=\"1\">"
                    +"  <tr><td></td>"
                    +"  </tr>";

        //Database Connection
        var conn = getAdoDb("ADODB.Connection");
        conn.open(conn_str, "", "");

       //Recordset
       var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
       strQuery = "SELECT * FROM GuestBook";
       rs.open(strQuery, conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic);

       if (!rs.bof) {
           rs.MoveFirst();

           while(!rs.eof) {

               if(document.layers){
            document.getElementById("one").open();

            document.getElementById("one").close();
               }
           else {

                    tablevar+="  <tr>"
                    +"    <td>"+"Sur Name: <br> Fore Name: <br> Home Address: <br> PinCode: <br> Contact Number: <br> E-mail: <br> Date of Birth: <br>  Nationality: <br> University: <br> Available Timings: <br> Interested Courses: <br> Other Courses:  <br> Expected Money:  <br> Any More Information: <br> "+"</td>"
                    +"    <td>"+rs.fields(0).value+"<br>"+rs.fields(1).value+"<br>"+rs.fields(2).value+"<br>"+rs.fields(3).value+"<br>"+rs.fields(4).value+"<br>"+rs.fields(5).value+"<br>"+rs.fields(6).value+"<br>"+rs.fields(7).value+"<br>"+rs.fields(8).value+"<br>"+rs.fields(9).value+"<br>"+rs.fields(10).value+"<br>"+rs.fields(11).value+"<br>"+rs.fields(12).value+"<br>"+rs.fields(13).value+"<br></td>"
      +"  </tr>";

                document.getElementById("one").innerHTML=tablevar;

                }

                rs.MoveNext();
            }
      }
      else{

          if(document.layers){
         document.getElementById("one").open();

         document.getElementById("one").close();
          }
          else{

        document.all("one").innerHTML="No Records To Display.";

          }
          //No Records.

      }
      conn.close();


       tablevar+= "</table>";

} catch(ex) {
     alert(ex.message);
}
}

//-->
</script>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [ActiveXObject is not defined and can't find variable: ActiveXObject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11101641/activexobject-is-not-defined-and-cant-find-variable-activexobject)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ActiveXObject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveX) is IE specific and you wont be able to execute that in a non IE browser.

Comment: how can i execute in firefox browser

Comment: Don't execute this in the browser. It's really quite crazy to implement a guest book entirely in JavaScript, including the database interaction. Do this server-side with ASP.NET, PHP or something similar instead

Answer (score 0):

Check this question:

[Is there a way to run ActiveX components in Firefox through the use of a plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326125/is-there-a-way-to-run-activex-components-in-firefox-through-the-use-of-a-plugin)