# ActiveXObject is not defined and can't find variable: ActiveXObject

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2

i want to create text file in local,  when i browse in Google chrome click of the button it is showing error like  **ActiveXObject is not defined** and  when i browse in safari click of the button it is showing error like  **can't find variable: ActiveXObject** . any one can help me.how can i achieve and create file .Thanq

```
<script>
      function createFile() {    
      var object = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");       
      var file = object.CreateTextFile("C:\\Hello.txt", true);
      file.WriteLine('Hello World');
      alert('Filecreated');
      file.WriteLine('Hope is a thing with feathers, that perches on the soul.'); 
      file.Close();
      }
    </script>
<input type="Button" value="Create File" onClick='createFile()'>
```

Comment: Even on IE, if you do this from a page served via HTTP, you're going to hit security blocks.

Answer (score 28):

`ActiveXObject` is available only on IE browser. So every other useragent will throw an error

On modern browser you could use instead [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications) or [File writer API](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-writer-api/) (currently implemented [only on Chrome](http://caniuse.com/filesystem))

Comment: File API is read only, so you can't.

Comment: Right, I improved my answer, thank you.

Answer (score 11):

`ActiveXObject` is non-standard and only supported by Internet Explorer on Windows.

There is no native cross browser way to write to the file system without using plugins, even the draft [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) gives read only access.

If you want to work cross platform, then you need to look at such things as signed Java applets (keeping in mind that that will only work on platforms for which the Java runtime is available).

Answer (score 2):

A web app can request access to a sandboxed file system by calling `window.requestFileSystem()`. Works in Chrome.

```
window.requestFileSystem = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
var fs = null;

window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1024 * 1024, function (filesystem) {
    fs = filesystem;
}, errorHandler);

fs.root.getFile('Hello.txt', {
    create: true
}, null, errorHandler);

function errorHandler(e) {
  var msg = '';

  switch (e.code) {
    case FileError.QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR:
      msg = 'QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR';
      break;
    case FileError.NOT_FOUND_ERR:
      msg = 'NOT_FOUND_ERR';
      break;
    case FileError.SECURITY_ERR:
      msg = 'SECURITY_ERR';
      break;
    case FileError.INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR:
      msg = 'INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR';
      break;
    case FileError.INVALID_STATE_ERR:
      msg = 'INVALID_STATE_ERR';
      break;
    default:
      msg = 'Unknown Error';
      break;
  };

  console.log('Error: ' + msg);
}
```

More info [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/).

Comment: thanks for your reply. i have used your code..on click of button it is giving. errorHandler is not defined. anything i have missed?