# Uncaught ReferenceError: ActiveXObject is not defined Error in Chrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome

i have this error in Chrome 
"Uncaught ReferenceError: ActiveXObject is not defined "

my code is

```
function loadModel() {

            //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            document.getElementById("lModelMsg").innerText = "Loading...";
            document.getElementById("lPartMsg").innerText = "";
            var dMfg = document.getElementById("dManufacturer");
            var id = dMfg.options[dMfg.selectedIndex].value;
            var xml = CreateAsset.LoadModel(id);
            var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
            var Flag;
            Flag = xmlDoc.loadXML(xml.value);
            if (Flag) {......................
```

Comment: You code works only in IE... In Chrome `ActiveXObject` really does not exist.

Comment: @Teemu is there any alternative of ActiveXObject for chrome???

Comment: possible duplicate of [ActiveXObject is not defined and can't find variable: ActiveXObject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11101641/activexobject-is-not-defined-and-cant-find-variable-activexobject)

Comment: install ietab for chrome, and it will solve your purpose.

Comment: see my Answer[ Active X solution for Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55527700/7990050)

Comment: Can anyone please let me know how to use new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"); in chrome ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ActiveX is a Microsoft-proprietary framework. It is supported only in MS products (i.e, IE)

You can use [jQuery's parseXML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) method as a cross-browser alternative.

Answer (score 6):

As stated by others, ActiveX is an IE-specific technology.

Try this:

```
if (window.DOMParser)
{ // Firefox, Chrome, Opera, etc.
    parser=new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(xml,"text/xml");
}
else // Internet Explorer
{
    xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xmlDoc.async=false;
    xmlDoc.loadXML(xml); 
}
```

Comment: then it gives this error "Object #<Document> has no method 'loadXML'"

Comment: Chrome should not be trying to use the `loadXML` call as that is the IE path; are you sure you cleared your cached version of the JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the security setting of your browser is blocking it.

If you try IE6 the code should work. You have to use a dead browser because the new browsers block it from working as part of a killbit fix that Microsoft did to fix a security issue.