# How to account for non IE browsers when using ActiveX

Tags: javascript, activex

I am using the following code to write to a `.csv` file

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script language="javascript">
    function WriteToFile(passForm) {
      var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
      var fileLoc = "C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\test\\sample.csv";
      var file = fso.CreateTextFile(fileLoc, true ); 
      file.writeline(passForm.FirstName.value + ',' + passForm.LastName.value);
      file.Close();
      alert('File created successfully at location: ' + fileLoc);
     }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <p>create a csv file with following details -</p>
  <form>
    Type your first name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" size="20">

    Type your last name: <input type="text" name="LastName" size="20">

    <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="WriteToFile(this.form)">
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
</br></br></html>
```

It works perfect for IE . However for other browsers it throws 
`Uncaught ReferenceError: ActiveXObject is not defined`

---

I checked online for possible solutions

Here is a [one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17927038/uncaught-referenceerror-activexobject-is-not-defined-error-in-chrome)

I tried to include that code into the above code , however it did not work .

Comment: Other browsers will not allow regular web page javascript to write to your file system for security reasons.

Comment: On a different note, the _language_ attribute of `<script>` is depreciated; if you want to specify this, set the _MIME_ in the _type_  attribute instead.