# How to add span tag to a selected text using jQuery and saving the change permanently in local html file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have created notes in html file locally and intend to use the file only locally in my computer. Let's say i have a code

```
<p> this is an example text</p>
```

I want to select the word example in the browser and preferably press a shortcut to change the code as

```
<p> this is an <span class="highlight">example</span> text</p>
```

and save this change in the same html file.

Especially, I have no clue on how to approach saving the changes in the same local html file.

Edit: I intend to use this notes only for personal use and will be only locally stored in my computer as a .html file.

Edit2: **Can this be achieved using php?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20720343/how-to-write-a-local-txt-with-javascript

Comment: corrected the </p> tag :)

Answer (score 2):

> but I have no clue on how to approach saving the changes in the same
>   local html file.

You can't change the source code of your HTML/JS/CSS file from browser. It posses a serious security risk to your application and hence will be prohibited by the browser.

If you want to remember that you have made this change, then save a value in either localstorage or cookie so that your program read this value at startup and make the change in your markup without a user event.

Comment: Since, I am intending to use the notes only for my personal use and store it locally in my computer, I am not worried about the security concerns or vulnerabilities if there is a way to achieve saving the changes in the same local html file.

Comment: OK, but the browser doesn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't write to the file system using HTML only - you can however use JS to generate an AJAX request to a server side script (ie PHP/Node/etc.) which in turn writes to a file.

You could retrieve most of the contents by accessing `document.body.parentNode.innerHTML` changes you've made to DOM since loading the page should be reflected here. It's worth noting that this attribute will not include the HTML tag, or the DTD - it will only include the head and body tags so you'll need to be sure to add them in your server side script.