# Writing Data to CSV File using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, csv, export-to-csv

I would like to write the data results from a form to the csv (or excel). I want to save this results in the server serverless (without php, etc.).

I have found this code:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script language="javascript">
    function WriteToFile(passForm) {
      var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
      var fileLoc = "C:\\sample.csv";
      var file = fso.CreateTextFile(fileLoc, true);
      file.writeline(passForm.FirstName.value + ',' +
                     passForm.LastName.value);
      file.Close();
      alert('File created successfully at location: ' + fileLoc);
     }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <p>create a csv file with following details -</p>
  <form>
    Type your first name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" size="20">

    Type your last name: <input type="text" name="LastName" size="20">

    <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="WriteToFile(this.form)">
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
</br></br></html>
```

But it does work only with IE.

How to solve this problem?

Regards

Comment: *I want to save this results in the server serverless (without php, etc.)*. And how do you think that would work?

Comment: If what you want is something that runs completely locally, with no server involved, and does things that are outside of the security model of the web, why not just write a simple native app?

Answer (score 1):

as i understand your question and searched i found that

> ActiveX is only supported by IE - the other browsers use a plugin
>   architecture called NPAPI. However, there's a cross-browser plugin
>   framework called Firebreath that you might find useful.

you can refer to this question

[refer question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11101641/activexobject-is-not-defined-and-cant-find-variable-activexobject)

[refer question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022568/activexobject-in-firefox-or-chrome-not-ie)