# How to read and show xslx file in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xlsx

I'm trying to read a xlsx file in html using javaScript but it seems my code is not so right as it should be.

I'm using this code:

```
    <script>
    function openRead(){
    var excel = activeXObject("Excel.Application");
            excel.visible = false;
            var file = exel.workbooks.open("C:\Users\Utilizador\Desktop\teste.xlsx").activeSheet.cell(1,1).value;

var div = document.getElementById("div1").text;
div = file;
}
</script>
```

Getting the following error

> activeXObject is not defined

I hope you guys can point me to the right direction!

Comment: any errors when running?

Comment: Yes, it says that activeXObject is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveXObject is available only on IE browser. So every other **useragent** will throw an error

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11101655/1172872

You can try existing libraries... (or see how they implemented it)

- http://sheetjs.com/  (https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx)
- http://oss.sheetjs.com/js-xls/