# ActiveXObject getting undefined in IE11

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get details from `ActiveXObject` boject but it is not working in `chrome` and `mozilla`. And also i checked in `IE11` but it getting `undefined` in console.

```
var INIngenico = new ActiveXObject("KioskVerifone.Verifone")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ActiveXObject is not defined and can't find variable: ActiveXObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11101641/activexobject-is-not-defined-and-cant-find-variable-activexobject)

Comment: `window.ActiveXObject` is only supported in IE. And since IE11 `window.ActiveXObject` is hidden from the DOM and can therefore no longer be used (https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/en-us/dn423948(v=vs.85).aspx)